# increment and decrement input form values in multiple rows with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my shopping cart page where the user can increment and decrement values of the quantity of products, I can have multiple products so i dont know how to change the values in multiple rows, every row have their own input of quantity

[image]

**my html code**

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="cart-form">
 <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"><input name="_token" 
  type="hidden" value="ikL1QisIpVm0CXTAXGqeaP5vf8ulkeUAlsa7jnFE">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" id="min">
    <input name="qty" id="quantity" type="text" value="1" class="qty">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" id="plus">                       
</form>
```

**my js code**

```
$('.minus').click(function(){
    if ($('#quantity').val() != 0)
        $('#quantity' ).val(parseInt($('#quantity').val()) - 1);
});

$('.plus').click(function(){
    $('#quantity').val(parseInt($('#quantity').val()) + 1);
});
```

Comment: And does every row have the same ID's as well?

Comment: Provide us with an fiddle?

Comment: What is `custom7`?

Comment: @trincot he made a typo, I tried his code using $ instead of custom7 and it worked just fine, there's the error ;)

Comment: That does not look like a typo to me though.

Comment: sorry about the custom7 , is the $ instead but how can i do with multiple rows, this only work with one row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have multiple identical ids (quantity).  You want to get the "right" quantity field based on its location relative to the +/- button that was clicked.

For minus, the quantity field is the next sibling:

```
$('.minus').click(function(){
  quantityField = $(this).next();
  if (quantityField.val() != 0) {
     quantityField.val(parseInt(quantityField.val(), 10) - 1);
  }
});
```

and for plus, the quantity field is the previous sibling

```
$('.plus').click(function(){
  quantityField = $(this).prev();
  quantityField.val(parseInt(quantityField.val(), 10) + 1);
});
```

Comment: this put a 1 or 0, for example if i have 1 put 11

Comment: I forgot to wrap the val() in parseInt, updated answer.

Comment: just perfect! you save my day

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you just made a typo in the following line,

```
$('#quantity' ).val(parseInt(custom7('#quantity').val()) - 1);
```

You'd probally want to change this into

```
$('#quantity' ).val(parseInt($('#quantity').val()) - 1);
```

`custom7` isn't part of jQuery, `$` is.
Here's a fiddle to show its working, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/homp99hm/)

Comment: sorry is $ not custom 7, but is other the problem

Comment: @Leoh look at the JSFiddle, it works the way it's supposed to? It's not a error in this code, but as @yezzz stated that duplicated ids may be the cause of this, make sure there is only one with the `id` quantity.

Comment: @MartijnEbbens yes thats work with one row, but i have multiple rows with one form for product